# Concept of separation of charges in lightning clouds

Tags: electrostatics

I have read in an article that when lightning strikes in the clouds the cloud disintegrates into two parts of which the negatively charged part is bigger than the positively charged one. Why does this happen?

Here is the screenshot of that article which is a textbook paragraph.

[image: textbook]

Comment: Could you link the article, please?

Comment: just a moment please i will link it

Comment: i have uploaded it you can see it now

Comment: this thing is included in our textbook and thats the reason i want to get it at any cost

Comment: It's from Physics textbook of CBSE NCERT. Rather you should try to read the previous concepts before the article in the book. You will surely get the reason. NCERT gives the best explanation for the concepts.

Comment: i read the whole for about 15 times but could'nt get any single sign of hope for that

Comment: as a side note, the article claims the average duration is 30 seconds for a lightning flash. Wikipedia has 30 microseconds. I'm going with wikipedia on this one; 30 seconds would be ridiculously huge

Comment: why was this question downvoted

Comment: @agharehanabbas Glad to hear my answer solved your problem. To also answer your question why you've been downvoted: I had to read your question several times to understand what you were asking, because you didn't write particularly clearly. After all, it's not like charge is disintegrating as in the sense that it vanishes. Try to formulate your questions more carefully in the future. Also, your reply towards Jim's legimite comment could be considered a little rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just missunderstood the textbook article. It says,

> There are ice particles in the clouds, which grow, collide, fracture
>   and break apart. The smaller particles acquire positive charge and the
>   larger ones negative charge.

Not the *clouds* grow, collide, fracture and break apart, but the *ice particles*. In fact, the article is a bit simplistic on *how* this leads to a separation of charges. Upon further research, you'll find that it is highly non-trivial and there seem to be a variety of effects at work. [This paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~colin/courses/AtmosElec/Saunders%20Charge%20Separation%20SSR%202008%20%281%29.pdf) explores them in great detail. One of the major contributions seems to be due to supercooled water:

Updrafts in the thunder cloud transport small droplets of water upwards. As the droplets rise they cool down but cannot freeze yet. They become [supercooled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooled_liquid). Meanwhile,  big "ice particle", i.e. hail, forms in the cold upper regions of the cloud and falls downwards due to gravity.

When the falling hail collides with the supercooled droplets, the latter freeze instantly, releasing their [latent heat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat) to the hail. Thus, the descending hail is always a bit warmer than its environment pushing it towards melting. The hail becomes also supercooled / "soft" and is then referred to as [graupel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graupel).

Now, when the falling graupel collides with other rising droplets of water, it rips off electrons from the droplet. [This site](http://www.srh.weather.gov/srh/jetstream/lightning/lightning.htm) refers to it as a *critical phenomenon*, in. A more thorough description may be found [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~colin/courses/AtmosElec/Saunders%20Charge%20Separation%20SSR%202008%20%281%29.pdf). However, as something related to the phase transition and the accompanying supercritical states of matter, it is bound to be complicated.

Bottom line is that the graupel acquires an additional negative charge due to the excess electrons. The droplet which were on their way up are missing it, so the upper part of the cloud is charged positively.

Comment: great answer jonas totally impressed with that answer